# I'm trying to add Customer Eligibility Card to a Shopify discount app that I'm building, however I'm stuck

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-app-bridge

0

So this is the first-ever app that I'm building for Shopify, I'm building a discount app using Shopify's own tutorial https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/selling-strategies/discounts/experience.

I've got all this up and running, however, I'd like to add a customer segment picker so the discount only works with specific customer segments, this way I can add automatic discounts based on customer segments.

I've tried integrating the customer eligibility card through the discount-app component. https://shopify.dev/docs/api/discounts/components/customer-eligibility-card

I'm just stuck as it uses a file import { fetchGraphQL } from "./authenticatedGraphQL"; // A request to proxy the GraphQL request. I have no idea what this does and how to replicate it to get this function working, any ideas?

I'm just stuck as it uses a file import { fetchGraphQL } from "./authenticatedGraphQL"; // A request to proxy the GraphQL request. I have no idea what this does and how to replicate it to get this function working, any ideas?